# Get value from multiple form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am doing a ASP.NET MVC project.

I have multiple forms in one page.

For example

```
<form method="post" action="" id="Form1" name="Form1">
    <textarea id="TextBox1" name="TextBox1" cols="8" rows="10"></textarea>
</form>

<form method="post" action="" id="Form2" name="Form2">
   <textarea id="TextBox2" name="TextBox2" cols="8" rows="10"></textarea>
</form>
```

In the controller, I want to get the value from TextBox2, what should I do?

If i use FormCollection form = new FormCollection();
which form did I get?

Thanks a lot

**UPDATED CODE**

Here is the link, when user click on it, the value of text box will be submitted.

```
    <%= Ajax.ActionLink("Submit Reply", "SubmitThisReply", "Home",
                    new { ParentID = item.QAID, ArticleID = item.ArticleID },
                    new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "QAContents", OnSuccess = hiddenDivName },
                    new { @class = "linkButton" })%>
```

Here is the code for the controller

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitThisReply(int ParentID, int ArticleID, FormCollection form)
    {
        //FormCollection form = new FormCollection();
        int UserID = Convert.ToInt16(Session["UserID"].ToString());
        string contentName ="txtReplyComment-"+ParentID.ToString();
        string content = form[contentName];

        QA replyQuestion = new QA();
        replyQuestion.ArticleID = ArticleID;
        replyQuestion.UserID = UserID;
        replyQuestion.ParentID = ParentID;
        replyQuestion.Content = "1";

        qaFunction.ReplyQA(replyQuestion);

        var allQA = bio.QAListByArticleID(ArticleID).ToList(); //Return Type: QAViews
        var firstLevelQA = allQA.Where(c => c.ParentID == null);

        ViewData["AllQA"] = allQA;
        ViewData["FirstLevelQA"] = firstLevelQA;


        if (!Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ArticleDetail", "Home", new { articleID = ArticleID });
        }

        return PartialView("QAControl", ViewData["FirstLevelQA"]);
    }
}
```

**Last Update**

Well, I guess I found the solution.

I just need to use a ajax form, and put a submit button inside that form...

Answer (score 1):

It depnds where your submit button lies. whichever form's submit button will be pressed form will be posted to the respective action. [This](http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/02/12/asp-net-mvc-handling-multiple-form-actions-on-one-view.aspx) link may help you

You will need to do something like this

```
<script>
function formsubmit()
{
 document.form1.action="Page Name here you want to go that
page";
 document.form1.submit();
}
</script>

<form name="form1" method="post">
<input type= text onblur="formsubmit();">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get the values of whichever form you submitted, but there is no submit button anywhere in your code.

Comment: actually I am using a ajax call, to post user's comment to the database. So there is no submit button at all... I just cannot capture the value from the text area... any help?

Comment: Do I need to use a Ajax form, instead of the regular form?